# GWT: Maven error: jar must be 'pom' to import the managed dependencies

Tags: java, maven, gwt, dependency-management

I made a sample GWT app using `webAppCreator`.

When running any `mvn` command, for example `mvn package`, I am getting this error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[WARNING] 'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.type' for com.google.gwt:gwt:jar must be 'pom' to import the managed dependencies. @ line 21, column 19
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.google.gwt:gwt-servlet:jar is missing. @ line 34, column 17
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.google.gwt:gwt-user:jar is missing. @ line 39, column 17
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.google.gwt:gwt-dev:jar is missing. @ line 44, column 17
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.google.gwt:gwt-codeserver:jar is missing. @ line 49, column 17
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.babken.stockwatcher:StockWatcher:1.0-SNAPSHOT (/home/void/workspace/stockwatcher/pom.xml) has 4 errors
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.google.gwt:gwt-servlet:jar is missing. @ line 34, column 17
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.google.gwt:gwt-user:jar is missing. @ line 39, column 17
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.google.gwt:gwt-dev:jar is missing. @ line 44, column 17
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.google.gwt:gwt-codeserver:jar is missing. @ line 49, column 17
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
```

Answer (score 1):

The `[WARNING]` line says everything - you need to add `<type>pom</type>` to `dependencyManagement` in your `pom.xml`.

Open your `pom.xml` and change the following part:

```
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <!-- ensure all GWT deps use the same version (unless overridden) -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt</artifactId>
        <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
```

to:

```
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <!-- ensure all GWT deps use the same version (unless overridden) -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt</artifactId>
        <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
```

This is a known bug in `webAppCreator`: https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=9054 . Update GWT to latest version. (Thanks Thomas Broyer).

Comment: You guessed wrong. It was an oversight, and is a [known bug](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=9054) in GWT 2.7.0, actually already fixed in `master` months ago.